# "Or" vs "and" in "don't like" phrases

Tags: conjunctions

Is this correct:

> I don't like reading **and** playing the guitar.

or should I use "or".

> I don't like reading **or** playing the guitar.

Is the "and" version incorrect? I mean that I don't like reading and I don't like playing the guitar.

Answer (score 4):

This native speaker would always use **or** to mean "I don't like reading and I also don't like playing the guitar."  *And* isn't "incorrect", but it makes the sentence mean something slightly different.  The reason for this is that *or* makes it clear that you don't like either one: whether you are reading or playing the guitar, you don't like it.  *And* sounds like it refers to the two activities *together*.  For example,

"I don't like eating or talking about business" = I don't like eating, and I also don't like talking about business.

"I don't like eating and talking about business" = I don't like to talk about business while I eat.

Comment: So it means that  "I don't like reading and playing the guitar" implies that I don't like reading and playing the guitar at the same time?

Comment: @user44430 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Out of interest, 'or' and 'and' can sometimes mean the same thing, for example in the statements:

> It prevents the document from being edited  **or**  duplicated.
>   It prevents the document from being edited  **and**  duplicated.

Both statements suggest that the document is prevented from being edited and also from being duplicated.

However, the first statement could also mean that the document is prevented from being edited, but not necessarily from being duplicated (one or the other).

The second statement could also mean that the editing and duplication of documents are dependent or allied, and that consequently, prevention cannot apply exclusively to one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for your intended meaning, you should use **or**:

> I don't like reading **and** playing the guitar.

Conveys two possible meanings to me.

**1. That you don't like simultaneously doing both:**

"Please read this book about Greek Mythology while you are at band practise later"

"Sorry - I don't like reading and playing the guitar"

**2. That those are the only 2 things in the world you don't like:**

"What are the only things in the world you don't like?"

"Reading and playing the guitar."

> I don't like reading **or** playing the guitar.

Conveys simply that these are 2 distinct things which you don't like.

In effect, in this case "or" actaully does mean "and", but because "and" carries the implication that the activities are simultaneous, we use "or" instead.